# Hive String operator concatenate by || double pipe

Tags: hive, hiveql

Language manual of Hive claims that double pipe string concatenation is supported, however I am unable to use this feature in my current version of HIVE 1.2.1000.2.4.3.6-2

```
hive> select 'a'||'b';
NoViableAltException(5@[323:1: atomExpression : ( ( KW_NULL )=> KW_NULL -> TOK_NULL | ( constant )=> constant | castExpression | caseExpression | whenExpression | ( functionName LPAREN )=> function | tableOrColumn | LPAREN ! expression RPAREN !);])
```

I was trying to find a version which starts to support that, but without any luck :-(

I know that I can use build in function concat to do the same thing, but I am rewriting bunch of Oracle views to Hive and I don't want to change things which can stay the same if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hive 2.2.0
The documentation is very clear about that

[image]
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators

Comment: funny, it is mentioned in multiple sections on this page, I was reading the one which is under Operators Precedences and Built-in Operators :-)   Sorry for that. Thanks

Comment: Why, why, why are built-in operators (which are by definition not user-defined) documented in a section on User-Defined Functions?  It's no wonder people can't find them.